# Can Indexed Arrays be used as associative arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I know that in PHP an indexed array that looks like:

```
$array = ("hello", "world")
```

is the same as an associative array that looks like:

```
$array = (0 => "hello", 1 => "world");
```

so my question is if code like this is valid :

```
 $hello = $array[$array["hello"]];
```

my thinking is that it translates to

```
$hello = $array[0]
```

, which will equal

```
$hello = "hello"
```

. In other words, will

```
$array["hello"]
```

equal 0?

Comment: Do you know how easy this would be to try for yourself? http://codepad.org/YOQvwr2E

Comment: `$hello = $array[$array["hello"]];` will fail.  You certainly can use the values of one array as keys in another array, but you cannot look up a value by its value.

Comment: array_search(), comes to mind if you just want the key of a known value: echo array_search('hello',$array); =0

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot fetch a key of some array element by its value right away... unless you switch keys and values with [array_flip](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php):

```
$arr = array('hello', 'world');
$arr = array_flip($arr);
print $arr['hello']; // 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's walk through the thinking:

```
$array = ("hello", "world") // This is implicitly indexed by integer.
```

is the same as:

```
$array = (0 => "hello", 1 => "world"); // Explicit indexing.
```

You can verify by doing `print_r($array)`; In either case, the output would show an indexed array. PHP arrays are all associative. Even if you did not specify a key, the values in an array are ordered by integer index numbers.

Now let's take a look at:

so my question is if code like this is valid :

```
 $hello = $array[$array["hello"]];
```

This is where the code will break. Why?

`$array["hello"]` is not a valid value. What this is referencing is "the value of the array's list at index "hello".

However, `array("hello", "world")` does not have an index key of "hello". Rather, it has a **value** "hello" which has implicitly the **key** index 0.

Make sure to read up on [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and understand that:

1. PHP arrays are all associative; keys can be strings, or if not explicitly set, will be integers.
2. Associative arrays are in the form of key => value pairs. If you have a key, you can find the value associated with it.
3. When trying to get a value from a PHP array, the syntax is: `$array['key']` or in the case of multidimensionals `$array['firstlevelkey']['secondlevelkey']` etc. The value that gets returned would be the value of the key => value pair at that particular key.

I hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

No, since "hello" is not a valid key in $array.

You can check if a key exist using array_key_exists(*key*,*array*)